# How can I run an executable program and send it input in one line on command line?

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments

Say, I have a program called "tree". It takes as input a text file containing some dictionary of English words, call it `engDict.txt`.

In my terminal, I would execute this program using the following command:

```
>> ./tree engDict.txt
```

Assuming this program automatically reads in the file and processed it. Then, it prompts the user: Would you like to exit the program (y/n)?

Now, my question is:

How can I send input to this program in one line?

For example, I tried the following, but it doesn't do what I'd like.

```
>> ./tree engDict.txt | n
```

or

```
>> ./tree engDict.txt ; n
```

Comment: You don't really need the `c++` tag there.  This is basically a `nix` question.

Comment: @Matt My bad. It was a suggested tag so I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close. The letter n should be written to the input.

```
  echo n | ./tree engDict.txt
```